# How to keep ownership to same user for dir

Tags: linux, chown, ownership

I have two users,memsql and 4px. I have copied dir from 4px user, home dir to memsql user home dir.

I want the permission for dir `poc` & `singlestore1` to be `memsql` , `memsql`. Instead of `memsql` & `4px` user in below logs.

Logs:

```
[memsql@rnd-2 ~]$ ls -al
total 32
drwxr-x---. 3 memsql 4px      20 Jan 13 07:17 poc
-rw-rw-r--. 1 memsql memsql 1032 Jan 13 08:16 setup.cnf
drwxrwxr-x. 5 memsql 4px    4096 Jan 13 03:11 singlestore1
-rw-------. 1 memsql memsql 2425 Jan 13 08:16 .viminfo
```

I tried chown command but `4px` user for both dir did not changed to `memsql` user.
Command I ran:

```
chown memsql singlestore1
```

Expected output:

Logs:

```
[memsql@rnd-2 ~]$ ls -al
total 32
drwxr-x---. 3 memsql memsql      20 Jan 13 07:17 poc
-rw-rw-r--. 1 memsql memsql 1032 Jan 13 08:16 setup.cnf
drwxrwxr-x. 5 memsql memsql   4096 Jan 13 03:11 singlestore1
-rw-------. 1 memsql memsql 2425 Jan 13 08:16 .viminfo
```

Comment: How exactly did you use the `chown` command?

Comment: `chown memsql singlestore1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/731587/how-to-keep-ownership-to-same-user-for-dir?noredirect=1#comment1388053_731587) you say that you used the command

```bash
chown memsql singlestore1
```

This command would set the owner of `singlestore1` to `memsql`.  However, you appear to want to set the *group* to `memsql`.  You can do this in three different ways:

1. Set both owner and group with `chown`:

   ```bash
   chown memsql:memsql singlestore1
   ```
2. Set only group with `chown` (this seems to work in practice on the systems that I'm using, but is strictly not how `chown` is supposed to be used):

   ```bash
   chown :memsql singlestore1
   ```
3. Set only group with `chgrp`:

   ```bash
   chgrp memsql singlestore1
   ```

Comment: See also `chgrp memsql: file` to set owner to `memsql` and group to the primary group of the `memsql` user.